# PHP code in the email form subject line

Tags: php

i'm trying to use some php code in the subject line of my mail form. The code i use is as follows:

```
$email_subject .= $words[$lang]["CONTACT_EMIL_SUBJECT"];
```

The form works fine, but i'm not receiving any email.
If i put in only text like this: $email_subject = "Message from my mail form";
Then i am receiving the email.

So can any one tell me wy this is not working?

This code: $words[$lang]["CONTACT_EMIL_SUBJECT" is getting a value from a file that is included at the top of the page. And i'm using the same kind of code in other places on my page and that is working fine. I'm using this to translate my site, so if a user is looking at my site with English translation, then the form values will also be in english in the email that i receive, and like wise if a user is using Swedish translation then the values in the email will be in Swedish.

Thank you.

Comment: What does `echo $words[$lang]["CONTACT_EMIL_SUBJECT"];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a fallback option by checking if the value can be found. If not, display an alternative.

```
<?php
$to = "hello@domain.com";
$subject = isset($words[$lang]['CONTACT_EMAIL_SUBJECT']) ? $words[$lang]['CONTACT_EMAIL_SUBJECT'] : "Fallback subject, couldn't find correct lang.";
$message = isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : "No message";

if ( mail($to, $subject, $message) ) {
    echo "Thanks, your message was sent!";
} else {
    echo "Oops, we hit an error.
}
?>
```

Comment: Where do you see `echo` in the question?

Comment: @Barmar - my bad! Not sure _what_ I saw.

Comment: Thank you this almost works, On English translation it works but i'm having problems with the Swedish translation. My Subject text is as follows: Swedish: Nytt meddelande från FCAB-Hemsida. English: New Message From FCAB-Homepage. In the Swedish translation there is a letter Å if i change this O then it works, so how can i include echo utf8_encode to the code? Thank you.

Comment: [PHP Mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) - see Example #4 which also covers encoding :)

Answer (score 0):

did you declare `global $words;` ?

Check This Out On Idea of local vs global variable
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

ex:

```
include "/langs/".$lang."/words.php";
//this you can make a folder langs with multiple languages folder defined by $lang
//make a words.php in the $lang folder. Some Examples are /langs/en_us/words.php or /langs/en_gb/words.php for great britan and so on
//inside words.php you add
//$words[$lang]["CONTACT_EMIL_SUBJECT"] = "Email Subject"; for english
//$words[$lang]["CONTACT_EMIL_SUBJECT"] = "Kontakt E-Mail Betreff"; for german
//and so on.
//adding include at top of page is a global variable so when you add to your code
global $words; //this says to look for the variable when you added it to the file in include.
echo $words[$lang]["CONTACT_EMIL_SUBJECT"];
```

So a Full Example:

```
<?PHP 
    include "/langs/".$lang."/words.php"; //include your language
    function yourfunction(){
        //some code....
        global $words; //finds the $words global this can be used in anyplace that includes words.php
        $email_subject .= $words[$lang]["CONTACT_EMIL_SUBJECT"];
        echo $email_subject;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, but i dont understand so much of that page. How would my code look like with the global in it? Thank you.